# What is the mainstream position of biologists and anthropologists on the issue of human race?

Tags: biology, anthropology

Race is perhaps one of the most controversial and sensitive issues in anthropology, biology, and other related fields. As a non-scientist, I've used google to probe the disparity between the positions of those who believe that race exists and those who don't. I would like to know what is the generally accepted or most popular stance on the issue of race. Is it that, there is only one human race, and all genetic differences between us are shallow? Or, is it that, different human races exist biologically speaking?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is race a discredited scientific concept in biology?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/399/is-race-a-discredited-scientific-concept-in-biology)

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) According to the [FAQ](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/faq#questions), Skeptics.SE is for researching the evidence behind the claims you hear or read. This question doesn't appear to have any doubtful claims to investigate. Please edit it to reference a notable claim and flag for moderator attention to re-open (or get 5 re-open votes).